# How to search the last occurrence of a string in a file and fetch the next line along with it in perl

Tags: perl

I have a log file where the errors will be mentioned as "ERROR" at the beginning of the line and the next line will have the detailed text about the error. I would like to search for the last occurrence of "ERROR" in the file so I can find the last error and print the next line or copy is the line to a variable.

In shell, I can try the below command which will help me to achieve the same. Can someone give me an equivalent Perl code?

grep -A1 ERROR sapinst.log | tail -2

As the log file will be huge (~5000+ lines), so I don't want to store it in an array.

Comment: Re "*As the log file will be huge (~5000+ lines)*", What's that, 500 KiB? That's not huge; that's tiny!

Comment: Re "*Can someone give me an equivalent Perl code?*", What's wrong with the code you already have? If you don't tell us what it is, how can we avoid doing it in Perl too?

Comment: Hi Ikegami, I don't want to use shell script inside my perl code.

Comment: Hi, I want to prong the line that contains "ERROR" and the next line after that.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to place the lines you might want to print in a buffer (array), replacing them if you find a later match.

```
my @buf;
my $keep = 0;
while (<>) {
   if (/ERROR/) {
      @buf = $_;    # Discard any earlier match in favour of this one.
      $keep = 1;    # Also keep one more line.
   }
   elsif ($keep) {
     --$keep;
     push @buf, $_;
   }
}

print(@buf);
```

---

The above usually behaves identically to the command you posted. However, in the event that there are two lines following the one containing `ERROR`, the above behaves differently than the command you posted.

`log1`:

```
ERROR foo1
foo2
meow
ERROR bar1
bar2
woof
```

`log2`:

```
ERROR foo1
foo2
meow
ERROR bar1
```

Your command:

```
$ grep -A1 ERROR log1 | tail -2
ERROR bar1
bar2

$ grep -A1 ERROR log2 | tail -2
--
ERROR bar1
```

My program:

```
$ ./last_error log1
ERROR bar1
bar2

$ ./last_error log2
ERROR bar1
```

That's probably an improvement.

Comment: Adjusted my answer in response to the adjustment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try a 2 long buffer of lines:

```
my $match = "no error found";
my @a = ("", "");
while (<STDIN>) {
    @a = ($a[1], $_);
    $match = $a[1] if $a[0] =~ /^ERROR/i;
}
print $match;
```

This prints the last error (or “no error found”). To get all the errors, change the assignment to match in the while loop to a print statement.

Comment: Hi Vincent, The above code is working when i incorporated it in my code. But i am getting a warning for "$a[0] is uninitialized." 

The error :
Use of uninitialized value $arr1[0] in pattern match (m//) at
        systemProvisioning.pl line 815, <FILE> line 1 (#1)
    (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
    defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
    To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.

Comment: That doesn't work if there's more than one match. The OP specifically said the only want the lines following the last match.

Comment: The sentence after the block of code explains how to get just the last match.

Comment: @SubhashreeKanungo - try initializing the a array with “@a = (“”,””);” before the whole loop.

Comment: @ikegami I was trying to show both the answer to the question and what I thought was a likely variant of the code.  In hindsight, the variant should have been described after the code block.  Updating it now.